# Powershell get return value from visual basic script

Tags: powershell, vbscript

I have some old code in visual basic script. Instead of re-writing this old code into PowerShell, I'd like to call the VB scripts from PowerShell and capture their return value.

How can I get the return value of a visual basic script in powershell?

Something like this:

```bsh
$returnValue = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock{.\vbs\legacyVbsFunction.vbs}
```

The visual basic function may look like this

```
Function MyFunction() As Double
    Return 3.87 * 2
End Function
```

Comment: a) Your alleged VBScript code is not VBScript code (VBScript doesn't support typed return values). b) The return value of a function does not set the exit code of the script. c) Exit codes are integers. Floating point values are not supported.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] that will allow us to reproduce the actual problem you're facing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to capture a VBScript's (stdout) *output*:

```bsh
$output = cscript.exe //nologo .\vbs\legacyVbsFunction.vbs
```

Note that `$output` will either be a single *string* - if the script outputs just 1 line - or an *array* of strings in case of *multi-line* output.

---

For **example**, assuming that `.\vbs\legacyVbsFunction.vbs` contains the following code:

```vb
Function MyFunction
    MyFunction = 3.87 * 2
End Function

' Call the function and print it to stdout.
Wscript.Echo(MyFunction)
```

You could capture the output and convert it to a `[double]` as follows:

```bsh
[double] $output = cscript.exe //nologo .\vbs\legacyVbsFunction.vbs
```

`$output` then contains `7.74`.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually embed a vbscript function right in powershell using a com object called ScriptControl, but it only works in 32-bit powershell, C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe:  [Embed VBS into PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33223892/embed-vbs-into-powershell)

```
function Call-VBScript
{
  $sc = New-Object -ComObject ScriptControl
  $sc.Language = 'VBScript'
  $sc.AddCode('
    Function MyFunction
      MyFunction = 3.87 * 2
    End Function
  ')
  $sc.CodeObject
}

$vb = Call-VBScript
$returnvalue = $vb.MyFunction()
"returnvalue is " + $returnvalue
```

I found out you can run a job as 32-bit:

```
$returnvalue = 
start-job {
  function Call-VBScript {
    $sc = New-Object -ComObject MSScriptControl.ScriptControl.1
      $sc.Language = 'VBScript'
      $sc.AddCode('
        Function MyFunction
          MyFunction = 3.87 * 2
        End Function
      ')
    $sc.CodeObject
  }

  $vb = call-vbscript
  $vb.MyFunction()
} -runas32 | wait-job | receive-job

"returnvalue is " + $returnvalue
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really have an exit code in the VBS, you have a return for a function.
To actually have a return code you must close the script with something like:

```
wscript.quit(0)
```

or

```
wscript.quit(returncode)
```

In the powershell script you must execute the vbs something like this:

```
(Start-Process -FilePath "wscript.exe" -ArgumentList "Script.vbs" -Wait -Passthru).ExitCode
```

Comment: `Start-Process` is not required. PowerShell stores the exit code of the last external command in the automatic variable `$LastExitCode`. You may need to run VBScripts with `cscript.exe` instead of the default `wscript.exe`, though.

Comment: Indeed, although i think it might work with wscript.exe as well.

Comment: Just tested it. `wscript.exe` can't be used either way, since it doesn't return the exit code (probably because it runs the script asynchronously).

Comment: Made a quick test. Created a vbscript which only has

wscript.quit(101)

And in a powershell script put the following command:
(Start-Process -FilePath "wscript.exe" -ArgumentList "C:\Users\theje\Desktop\Tests\Teeets.vbs" -Wait -Passthru).ExitCode

Worked well:

PS C:\Users\theje> (Start-Process -FilePath "wscript.exe" -ArgumentList "C:\Users\theje\Desktop\Tests\Teeets.vbs" -Wait -Passthru).ExitCode
101

Comment: Ah, I had omitted the parameter `-PassThru`. Makes sense now. But even so, `wscript.exe` would only be usable with `Start-Process -Wait -PassThru`, so I'd still recommend using `cscript.exe` instead.